# How to make encoder work with two libraries?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

First I'd like to say I'm very new to c++, that's why I'm using the Arduino core and libraries on ESP32, and I would like to apologize for the dumpster fire you're about to see below.

Simply making a custom keyboard with buttons and encoders. When booted, select one of two modes: blekeyboard or ble midi control surface.

The button works in both modes but the encoder only works in whichever mode is declared last. (so in this script order, both the encoder and button in mode 1 blekeyboard works, while only the button works in mode 2.)

What did I do wrong and what can I do? Any suggestions regarding the problem or the overall script is welcome.

Thank you in advance.

```
#include <Arduino.h>

#include <BleKeyboard.h>
BleKeyboard bleKeyboard;

#define ESP32
#include <encoder.h>
#include <Control_Surface.h>
#include <MIDI_Interfaces/BluetoothMIDI_Interface.hpp>
BluetoothMIDI_Interface midi;

const int usermodebutton1 = 2;
const int usermodebutton2 = 0;
int usermode = 0;

// ---------------------- mode 2 MIDI Input Elements ------------------------ //

using namespace MIDI_Notes;
NoteButton csButton1 = {
    2,
    note(C, 4),
};
CCRotaryEncoder csEnc1 = {
    {26, 25},     // pins
    MCU::V_POT_1, // MIDI address (CC number + optional channel)
    1,            // optional multiplier if the control isn't fast enough
};

// -------------------------- mode 1 blekeyboard --------------------------- //

int kbutton1 = 2;
int kbutton1State;
int keyInterval = 400000;
Encoder kencoder1(25, 26);
int encInterval = 5000;
TickType_t currentTime;
TickType_t previousTime;
long enc1_oldPos = -999;

// ============================================================================= //

void setup()
{
    pinMode(usermodebutton1, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(usermodebutton2, INPUT_PULLUP);

    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("select mode:");

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

    while (true)
    {
        if (digitalRead(usermodebutton1) == LOW)
        {
            usermode = 1;
            Serial.println("mode 1 selected");
            break;
        }
        if (digitalRead(usermodebutton2) == LOW)
        {
            usermode = 2;
            Serial.println("mode 2 selected");
            break;
        }
        delay(1000);
    }

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

    if (usermode == 1)
    {
        Serial.println("setup mode 1");
        Serial.println("Starting BLE work...");
        bleKeyboard.begin();
        pinMode(kbutton1, INPUT_PULLUP);
        previousTime = 0;
    }
    if (usermode == 2)
    {
        Serial.println("setup mode 2");
        Serial.println("Control Surface BLE starting...");
        RelativeCCSender::setMode(relativeCCmode::TWOS_COMPLEMENT);
        Control_Surface.begin(); // Initialize Control Surface
    }
}

// ============================================================================= //

void loop()
{
    while (usermode == 1)
    {
        while (bleKeyboard.isConnected())
        {
            // mode 1 encoders
            long enc1_newPos = kencoder1.read();
            currentTime = esp_timer_get_time();

            if (enc1_newPos < enc1_oldPos && currentTime - previousTime > encInterval)
            {
                enc1_oldPos = enc1_newPos;
                previousTime = currentTime;
                // bleKeyboard.write(KEY_MEDIA_VOLUME_DOWN);
                Serial.print("enc1: ");
                Serial.println(enc1_newPos);
            }
            if (enc1_newPos > enc1_oldPos && currentTime - previousTime > encInterval)
            {
                enc1_oldPos = enc1_newPos;
                previousTime = currentTime;
                // bleKeyboard.write(KEY_MEDIA_VOLUME_UP);
                Serial.print("enc1: ");
                Serial.println(enc1_newPos);
            }

            // mode 1 keys
            kbutton1State = digitalRead(kbutton1);
            if (kbutton1State == LOW && currentTime - previousTime > keyInterval)
            {
                previousTime = currentTime;
                Serial.println("button 1 pressed");
                bleKeyboard.print("1");
            }
        }
    }
    while (usermode == 2)
    {
        Control_Surface.loop(); // Refresh all elements
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing that stands out to me, is the fact you've got a single piece of hardware - the encoder .Yet you're using 2 different libraries to access it. Without looking at the 2 libraries' source, I'd suspect there to be a problem with clashing interrupts. What problem were you trying to solve by adding a second library to interact with the single piece of hardware?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code needs general tidying up. Do not instantiate an object after the #include or #define section.

Avoid doing this:

```
#include <BleKeyboard.h>
BleKeyboard bleKeyboard;

#include <MIDI_Interfaces/BluetoothMIDI_Interface.hpp>
BluetoothMIDI_Interface midi;
```

I generally organise my code as:

```
// Include libraries
#include <lib1.h>
#include <lib2.h>
...

// Macros
#define SOMETHING_FUNNY value  // see the Macro name in capitals?
#define SOMETHING_USEFUL anothervalue
...

/*
* Variables Section.
* Also, I usually categorize my variables section by type: floats, integers, chars, etc. If I ever use booleans I pack them in a section called 'flags'. Also, if a boolean is used inside an interrupt it should be volatile
*/

Type var_name1 = initial_value;    // the initaliztion is optional
AnotherType var_name2;
...

// Object instantiation
ClassName object1;
AnotherClassName object2 = new AnotherClassName(constructor_parameters);
...

//Setup Function

void setup(){
// Serial Port initialization goes first
Serial.begin(baudrate);

// Initialization routines --> use functions! 

}

void loop(){
// Check for states of your FSM and call the respective function 
}

// Functions definitions

output type myFunction1(args){
// Routine
}

...
```

Second, your code shouts to me 'Finite-States Machines', which is basically what you are implementing but not in a conventional way. Please read Nick Gammon's amazing [tutorial](https://www.gammon.com.au/statemachine) on FSMs. This way, you will enumerate your states and trigger actions or events depending on the user's selection or hardware inputs without blocking the flow of the code.

Now, I assume that you have read both the .cpp files from your two libraries and checked if there are no conflicts between them? Also, which `encoder.h` library are you using? It looks like Paul Stoffregen's [library](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/Encoder), is it? I ask because his library is heavily based on interrupts and it was coded with some ASM blocks that might be not optimized for the ESP32, but please don't quote me on that. As enhzflep said:

> I'd suspect there to be a problem with clashing interrupts.

and I could not agree more on that. If you are using that library, there is a Macro that could save your life:

```
#define ENCODER_DO_NOT_USE_INTERRUPTS
```

used in [this](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/Encoder/blob/master/examples/NoInterrupts/NoInterrupts.pde) example from the library's repo